# NT_STATUS_ILLEGAL_CHARACTER Error when use SMB external storage on the Owncloud server 10.0.9

Tags: nfs, smb, owncloud

I have a problem with Owncloud server 10.0.9 on CentOS7.5,
 
I can connect to SMB external storage (Qnap NAS storage) When access to a directory name in the Thai language I face to error "This directory is unavailable, please check the logs or contact the administrator".

This is some an error  log "message : Exception: Unknown error (NT_STATUS_ILLEGAL_CHARACTER)". 
What should I do for fixing it. 
 Some error log 1 line 
{"reqId":"W5CICcWjPsyMxSgKIiEFeQAAAAA","level":4,"time":"2018-09-06T01:51:05+00:00","remoteAddr":"192.168.1.35","user":"wannacha","app":"webdav","method":"PROPFIND","url":"/remote.php/webdav/ISO-GDL","message":"Exception: Unknown error (NT_STATUS_ILLEGAL_CHARACTER) for /Note \u0e01\u0e32\u0e23\u0e1b\u0e23\u0e30\u0e0a\u0e38\u0e21\u0e27\u0e31\u0e19\u0e17\u0e35\u0e48 3 \u0e01.\u0e22.61: {\"Exception\":\"Icewind\\SMB\\Exception\\Exception\",\"Message\":\"Unknown error (NT_STATUS_ILLEGAL_CHARACTER) for \/Note \u0e01\u0e32\u0e23\u0e1b\u0e23\u0e30\u0e0a\u0e38\u0e21\u0e27\u0e31\u0e19\u0e17\u0e35\u0e48 3 \u0e01.\u0e22.61\",\"Code\":0,\"Trace\":\"#0 \/var\/www\/html\/owncloud\/apps\/files_external\/3rdparty\/icewind\/smb\/src\/Exception\/Exception.php(35): Icewind\\SMB\\Exception\\Exception::unknown('\/Note \\xE0\\xB8\\x81\\xE0\\xB8\\xB2\\xE0\\xB8\\xA3...', 'NT_STATUS_ILLEG...')\n#1 \/var\/www\/html\/owncloud\/apps\/files_external\/3rdparty\/icewind\/smb\/src\/Wrapped\/Parser.php(85): Icewind\\SMB\\Exception\\Exception::fromMap(Array, 'NT_STATUS_ILLEG...', '\/Note \\xE0\\xB8\\x81\\xE0\\xB8\\xB2\\xE0\\xB8\\xA3...')\n#2 \/var\/www\/html\/owncloud\/apps\/files_external\/3rdparty\/icewind\/smb\/src\/Wrapped\/Share.php(403): Icewind\\SMB\\Wrapped\\Parser->checkForError(Array, '\/Note \\xE0\\xB8\\x81\\xE0\\xB8\\xB2\\xE0\\xB8\\xA3...')\n#3 \/var\/www\/html\/owncloud\/apps\/files_external\/3rdparty\/icewind\/smb\/src\/Wrapped\/Share.php(165): Icewind\\SMB\\Wrapped\\Share->parseOutput(Array, '\/Note \\xE0\\xB8\\x81\\xE0\\xB8\\xB2\\xE0\\xB8\\xA3...')\n#4 \/var\/www\/html\/owncloud\/apps\/files_external\/lib\/Lib\/Storage\/SMB.php(141): Icewind\\SMB\\Wrapped\\Share->stat('\/Note \\xE0\\xB8\\x81\\xE0\\xB8\\xB2\\xE0\\xB8\\xA3...')\n#5 \/var\/www\/html\/owncloud\/apps\/files_external\/lib\/Lib\/Storage\/SMB.php(548): OCA\\Files_External\\Lib\\Storage\\SMB->getFileInfo('Note \\xE0\\xB8\\x81\\xE0\\xB8\\xB2\\xE0\\xB8\\xA3\\xE0...')\n#6 \/var\/www\/html\/owncloud\/lib\/private\/Files\/Storage\/Common.php(102): OCA\\Files_External\\Lib\\Storage\\SMB->filetype('Note \\xE0\\xB8\\x81\\xE0\\xB8\\xB2\\xE0\\xB8\\xA3\\xE0...')\n#7 \/var\/www\/html\/owncloud\/lib\/private\/Files\/Storage\/Common.php(136): OC\\Files\\Storage\\Common->is_dir('Note \\xE0\\xB8\\x81\\xE0\\xB8\\xB2\\xE0\\xB8\\xA3\\xE0...')\n#8 \/var\/www\/html\/owncloud\/lib\/private\/Files\/Storage\/Common.php(156): OC\\Files\\Storage\\Common->isCreatable('Note \\xE0\\xB8\\x81\\xE0\\xB8\\xB2\\xE0\\xB8\\xA3\\xE0...')\n#9 \/var\/www\/html\/owncloud\/lib\/private\/Files\/Storage\/Common.php(625): OC\\Files\\Storage\\Common->getPermissions('Note \\xE0\\xB8\\x81\\xE0\\xB8\\xB2\\xE0\\xB8\\xA3\\xE0...')\n#10 \/var\/www\/html\/owncloud\/lib\/private\/Files\/Storage\/Wrapper\/Wrapper.php(577): OC\\Files\\Storage\\Common->getMetaData('Note \\xE0\\xB8\\x81\\xE0\\xB8\\xB2\\xE0\\xB8\\xA3\\xE0...')\n#11 \/var\/www\/html\/owncloud\/lib\/private\/Files\/Storage\/Wrapper\/Wrapper.php(577): OC\\Files\\Storage\\Wrapper\\Wrapper->getMetaData('Note \\xE0\\xB8\\x81\\xE0\\xB8\\xB2\\xE0\\xB8\\xA3\\xE0...')\n#12 \/var\/www\/html\/owncloud\/lib\/private\/Files\/Storage\/Wrapper\/Availability.php(459): OC\\Files\\Storage\\Wrapper\\Wrapper->getMetaData('Note \\xE0\\xB8\\x81\\xE0\\xB8\\xB2\\xE0\\xB8\\xA3\\xE0...')\n#13 \/var\/www\/html\/owncloud\/lib\/private\/Files\/Storage\/Wrapper\/Encryption.php(177): OC\\Files\\Storage\\Wrapper\\Availability->getMetaData('Note \\xE0\\xB8\\x81\\xE0\\xB8\\xB2\\xE0\\xB8\\xA3\\xE0...')\n#14 \/var\/www\/html\/owncloud\/lib\/private\/Files\/Storage\/Wrapper\/Wrapper.php(577): OC\\Files\\Storage\\Wrapper\\Encryption->getMetaData('Note \\xE0\\xB8\\x81\\xE0\\xB8\\xB2\\xE0\\xB8\\xA3\\xE0...')\n#15 \/var\/www\/html\/owncloud\/lib\/private\/Files\/Storage\/Wrapper\/Checksum.php(202): OC\\Files\\Storage\\Wrapper\\Wrapper->getMetaData('Note \\xE0\\xB8\\x81\\xE0\\xB8\\xB2\\xE0\\xB8\\xA3\\xE0...')\n#16 \/var\/www\/html\/owncloud\/lib\/private\/Files\/Cache\/Scanner.php(116): OC\\Files\\Storage\\Wrapper\\Checksum->getMetaData('Note \\xE0\\xB8\\x81\\xE0\\xB8\\xB2\\xE0\\xB8\\xA3\\xE0...')\n#17 \/var\/www\/html\/owncloud\/lib\/private\/Files\/Cache\/Scanner.php(153): OC\\Files\\Cache\\Scanner->getData('Note \\xE0\\xB8\\x81\\xE0\\xB8\\xB2\\xE0\\xB8\\xA3\\xE0...')\n#18 \/var\/www\/html\/owncloud\/lib\/private\/Files\/Cache\/Scanner.php(426): OC\\Files\\Cache\\Scanner->scanFile('Note \\xE0\\xB8\\x81\\xE0\\xB8\\xB2\\xE0\\xB8\\xA3\\xE0...', 3, '712', NULL, true)\n#19 \/var\/www\/html\/owncloud\/lib\/private\/Files\/Cache\/Scanner.php(394): OC\\Files\\Cache\\Scanner->handleChildren('', false, 3, '712', true, -1)\n#20 \/var\/www\/html\/owncloud\/lib\/private\/Files\/Cache\/Scanner.php(327): OC\\Files\\Cache\\Scanner->scanChildren('', false, 3, 712, true)\n#21 \/var\/www\/html\/owncloud\/lib\/private\/Files\/View.php(1368): OC\\Files\\Cache\\Scanner->scan('', false)\n#22 \/var\/www\/html\/owncloud\/lib\/private\/Files\/View.php(1409): OC\\Files\\View->getCacheEntry(Object(OC\\Files\\Storage\\Wrapper\\Checksum), '', 'ISO-GDL')\n#23 \/var\/www\/html\/owncloud\/apps\/dav\/lib\/Connector\/Sabre\/ObjectTree.php(179): OC\\Files\\View->getFileInfo('ISO-GDL')\n#24 \/var\/www\/html\/owncloud\/lib\/composer\/sabre\/dav\/lib\/DAV\/Server.php(966): OCA\\DAV\\Connector\\Sabre\\ObjectTree->getNodeForPath('ISO-GDL')\n#25 \/var\/www\/html\/owncloud\/lib\/composer\/sabre\/dav\/lib\/DAV\/Server.php(1665): Sabre\\DAV\\Server::getPropertiesIteratorForPath('ISO-GDL', Array, 1)\n#26 \/var\/www\/html\/owncloud\/lib\/composer\/sabre\/dav\/lib\/DAV\/CorePlugin.php(355): Sabre\\DAV\\Server->generateMultiStatus(Object(Generator), false)\n#27 [internal function]: Sabre\\DAV\\CorePlugin->httpPropFind(Object(Sabre\\HTTP\\Request), Object(Sabre\\HTTP\\Response))\n#28 \/var\/www\/html\/owncloud\/lib\/composer\/sabre\/event\/lib\/EventEmitterTrait.php(105): call_user_func_array(Array, Array)\n#29 \/var\/www\/html\/owncloud\/lib\/composer\/sabre\/dav\/lib\/DAV\/Server.php(479): Sabre\\Event\\EventEmitter->emit('method:PROPFIND', Array)\n#30 \/var\/www\/html\/owncloud\/lib\/composer\/sabre\/dav\/lib\/DAV\/Server.php(254): Sabre\\DAV\\Server->invokeMethod(Object(Sabre\\HTTP\\Request), Object(Sabre\\HTTP\\Response))\n#31 \/var\/www\/html\/owncloud\/apps\/dav\/appinfo\/v1\/webdav.php(64): Sabre\\DAV\\Server->exec()\n#32 \/var\/www\/html\/owncloud\/remote.php(165): require_once('\/var\/www\/html\/o...')\n#33 {main}\",\"File\":\"\/var\/www\/html\/owncloud\/apps\/files_external\/3rdparty\/icewind\/smb\/src\/Exception\/Exception.php\",\"Line\":17}"}

Comment: Stop using characters that are not allowed..? D: Does SMB support Unicode characters? If so, does Owncloud *and* Qnap NAS support such (and with the same encoding)?

Comment: Voting to move to SuperUser because it doesn't not seem to be access issues *from* code under development.